# Is there a hierarchy inferring algorithm available in python?

Tags: python, excel, vba, automation, hierarchy

We receive chart of account with more than a thousand rows, we spend hours to segregate this data into hierarchies by adding their values (trial and error). Unfortunately we can't do this by account names as they can be in any languages and form. Is there a ready algorithm available in python to infer hierarchy based on the values mentioned?

Below is the sample input and output, I have colored these for your understanding.

[image: Input Data]

[image: Output Data]

I can understand that no algorithm will be 100% accurate but if we can classify 70%-80% of accounts it would be an achievement. I can also code in VBA if someone has an idea to do this.

I have tried to run cumulative sums and cumulative differences, but unable find steps ahead.

Comment: In Output Data,column Level 2, shouldn't the first row be *Total Service* rather than *Service A*?

Comment: If they're always in order like that, can you simply take the sum of previous rows and see if they add to the current row? If they do, take it to be a sub-total row.

Comment: They they will always be in order, but I can't figure our if a value mentioned is Level 3 or Level 2 or may be Level 1

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the list of values to the desired table assuming:

- Each subgroup begins when approximately equals the rows above since the previous grouping
- The Last row has the name of the Level 1 group (i.e. Total Revenue)

**Code**

Process input data as data frame

```
import math

import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

def grouping(df):
    ''' Convert tablular values into nested dictionary
        Assumptions
            Subgroup begin with word Total
            Overall Group is the last row
    '''
     # List of Dataframes for each subgroup found
    result = []
    
    # Create new Empty data frame for subgroup
    subgroup_df = pd.DataFrame({'Level 1': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
                   'Level 2': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
                   'Level 3': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
                   'Values': pd.Series(dtype='float')})

    subgroup_total = 0
    for index, (account, value) in enumerate(zip(df['Account'], df['Values']), start = 1):
        if index == len(df):
            continue
        if math.isclose(subgroup_total, value, abs_tol  = 0.02):
            # current value equals sum of previous rows in subgroup
            subgroup_df['Level 2'] = account

            result.append(subgroup_df)
            # New empty dataframe for subgroup
            subgroup_df = pd.DataFrame({'Level 1': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
                   'Level 2': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
                   'Level 3': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
                   'Values': pd.Series(dtype='float')})
            subgroup_total = 0
        else:
            # within group
            subgroup_df.loc[len(subgroup_df.index)] = ["", "", account, value]
            subgroup_total += value
            
    result_df = pd.concat(result, ignore_index = True)
        
    result_df['Level 1'] = account
   
    return result_df
```

**Example Usage**

```
# Usage
# Get data from excel (workbook test.xlsx with worksheet name test
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', 'test')

# Generate table from nested dictionary
table = grouping(df)

print(tabulate(table, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
|    | Level 1       | Level 2        | Level 3   |   Values |
|----+---------------+----------------+-----------+----------|
|  0 | Total Revenue | Total Service  | Service A |    10.79 |
|  1 | Total Revenue | Total Products | Product A |     4.93 |
|  2 | Total Revenue | Total Products | Product B |     4.81 |
|  3 | Total Revenue | Total Products | Product C |     4.18 |
|  4 | Total Revenue | Total Products | Product D |     4.52 |
|  5 | Total Revenue | Total Food     | Food A    |     5.09 |
|  6 | Total Revenue | Total Food     | Food B    |     5.6  |
|  7 | Total Revenue | Total Food     | Food C    |     5.12 |
|  8 | Total Revenue | Total Food     | Food D    |     5.24 |
|  9 | Total Revenue | Total Food     | Food E    |     5.19 |
| 10 | Total Revenue | Total Food     | Food F    |     5.75 |
+----+---------------+----------------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: Hello @DarryIG, first of all many thanks your answer. Unfortunately, the account names are random and can be in any language (like French, German etc.). I am looking to infer the hierarchy from the values column, by adding them and finding the correct match.

Comment: @Ravichawla so we only know a subgroup is completed because the row value is the sum of the rows before?  Is that what you mean by inferring from the value?

Comment: Yes, a row value will be sum of (some) of the rows above. But we don't know how many rows. For an example while calculating total products in above example, total services shall not be used. There can be many Level 1, 2 and 3 entries.

Comment: @Ravichawla modified it so groups are formed when the rows above sum to within 2 cents ($0.02 i.e. sum is not exact).  Also, changed to reading data from Excel since you're using Excel.